# Use css grid to display items and build a first fixed column

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a series of red boxes and I want to place them in a grid:

[image]

As in the picture, I have tried to put the boxes in a grid and it works fine but I would like to have the boxes centered in the container, not always on the left.
My code:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/**
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
*/

.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px 20px
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To center the boxes I tried building a new div (`container`) and treat it as `flex` but it seems not to work. Why?

This is a problem but not that serious. The important thing is the following:

[image]

This above is what I would like to create: at the beginning of each line there must be a cyan rectangle aligned with the red boxes.
These cyan rectangles have a fixed size and there must be one on each line.

I really don't know how to do that thing.
I need a big help, hope you can help me

Comment: justify-items: center; on the grid container?

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is to center the content ok, thanks. Can you help me about how to place the cyan boxes on the left?